# Auto-increment subquery in tsql select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a T-SQL select statement and I want to auto-increment a column in it (that doesn't exist in the database)

```
select dbo.a, dbo.b, dbo.c, select @d:=1; @increment:=@increment+1 AS d
```

Is this possible?

Comment: SQL Server 2000 should be retired soon - even the 2005 version isn't officially supported by MS anymore....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL 2005 or later:

```
SELECT dbo.a, dbo.b, dbo.c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE()) AS d
```

to order the rows as they are returned form the DB.  If you want to specify an order you can do so:

```
SELECT dbo.a, dbo.b, dbo.c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dbo.a) AS d
```

For SQL 2000 and earlier you need a unique value to order by:

```
SELECT dbo.a, dbo.b, dbo.c, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo d2 WHERE d2.a <= dbo.a) AS d
FROM dbo
```

or if you don't need a single SELECT:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(int,1,1) ID, dbo.a, dbo.b, dbo.c
INTO #Temp
FROM dbo

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Comment: I have SQL2000. Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pull it off with something like:

```
select dbo.a, dbo.b, dbo.c,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by dbo.a) as d from somewhere;
```

My answer assumed SQL Server 2005+, I think D Stanley answer will help you in 2000.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` was new for SQL Server 2005, OP is using SQL Server 2000